# Rails - Assigning values to data entered by users in a model's form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model, fixnum

I have a model, Statistic, that has 6 statistics for a Character model. Users can enter values for Strength, Intelligence and so on. What I want to do is automatically assign a value for a bonus or a penalty based on the value entered by the user. For example, if a 10 or 11 is entered, the bonus will be 0. If a 14 or 15 is entered, it will be 2. Any tips on how to write this method? Thanks!

---

This has been a big help, but I've hit another snag. I've defined this in the Show method in Characters controller as such:

```
@con_modifier = @character.statistic.con_modifier
```

So I can call it from my Character view (where most of this information is displayed) I've got a Fortitude model for Fortitude saves, and I'd like to use the con_modifier in the logic to calculate a total. How do I call a foreign model correctly this way? I have:

```
def total
  fortitude_base.to_i + ability.to_i + magic.to_i + misc.to_i
end
```

And I tried changing it to:

```
def total
  fortitude_base.to_i + @con_modifier + magic.to_i + misc.to_i
end
```

But then I get this error:

```
nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

So obviously it isn't calling up the correct information. Any ideas? Do I need to define it in my Fortitudes controller as well, or can I simply define it in the Fortitude model and call it in the view that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smells like D&D. Consulting my old Player's Handbook indicates that the modifier for an attribute value of `n` is simply `(n - 10) / 2`.

So you'd just the attribute value through that simple formula and you'd have your modifier. I'd probably have a class method in the Attribute class:

```
class Attribute
    #...
    def self.modifier_for(attribute_score)
        (attribute_score.to_i - 10) / 2
    end
end
```

And then hook that up to your Player with something like this:

```
class Player
    #...
    def wis_modifier
        Attribute.modifier_for(wis)
    end
    def modifier(attr)
        self.send(attr.to_s + '_modifier')
    end
end

will_save += p.modifier(:wis)
```

You could probably get fancier if you wanted but simple is a good start and you can always get your local cleric to heal your code (or use your +3 Flaming Ax of Code Refactoring) later if necessary.

Comment: Yep, DnD! I'm working on a character sheet application, and I figured I'd save players some headaches and automate things that CAN be automated. However, how will the logic you show handle an odd score? 19 also has a modifier of +4 (like 18) but the logic will show this as 9 / 2, or 4.5. Will the .to_i automatically round it to 4, or is there a method to round fractional numbers?

Comment: @illbzo1: I added the `to_i` as a bit of paranoia to force the arithmetic into Fixnum mode so everything will be done with integers where 9/2 is 4 and -5/2 is -3. If your scores are Fixnums already then you don't need the `to_i` at all. There's also the `floor` method on Float if you end up in floating point land.

Comment: Fairly certain they ARE fixnums as is, since I got a fixnum-related error with the logic I tried prior to posting this question. I'll take a look this evening and try the methods you've shown. Thanks for clearing up my confusion about to_i and rounding, btw!

Comment: @illbzo1: If they are Fixnums then you can drop the `to_i`. You'd just need to make sure that you handle missing attributes (such as the Int of a Giant Wasp) properly or you'll get `nil` errors.